# Removing border spacing for the one tr in table

Tags: jquery, css, datatable

Is it possible to remove border spacing for one table row.I'm using jQuery data table.Clicking on the title there is a collapse container that is tr.I want to remove the border spacing for that particular tr.

Comment: share your code. So i can help you

Comment: Spacing is off by default. I think you're referring to the cell padding?

Comment: in that data table default spacing is there(border-spacing: 0 10px !important;). I want to remove this spacing for one tr ie, collapsed tr that we are showing extra details.